# Sku in Magento Product Page Description

Tags: magento-1.9

I need get the sku attribute in the product page description of my Magento site as the attribute does not show there by default, that's the first bit, the second bit is I need to know where to insert the code on the view.phtml

Comment: Hi Leon and welcome to MageOverflow. What have you tried? What have you expected and what was the result? Please edit your post and request reopening after adding more details

Comment: I have added this to view.phtml and works fine - one extra thing I am trying to get is to show the name SKU before the product code as at the moment just the sku code is showing on the product page and what I need is the title SKU to show just before the sku code itself <div class="std">
    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getSku()), 'sku') ?>
 </div

Comment: Please edit your answer to add informations. code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Your Theme for example I am Considering default Magento Theme Magento 1.9 RWD theme so file path should be

`app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

you can find below code

```
  <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
       <div class="short-description">
            <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
  <?php endif;?>
```

After That add this code

```
 <div class="std">
    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getSku()), 'sku') ?>
 </div>
```

Or you can direct Print using Object

```
echo $_product->getSku();
```

Or

```
echo $_product->getData('sku');
```

This are the different ways to access the Any attribute in Magento.

**Syntax Is**

```
echo $_product->getData('Attribute Code');
```

Comment: Hey Keyul Thanks a mil! That works great! I see the sku code returned under short description, the thing is how do I get it under the product title and where to insert correctly and do you know a way to get it to say SKU: as opposed to just the code. What I mean is the code is there eg 234344 and I would like to have it as SKU:234344

Comment: please explain me again I didn't getting you where you want to display

Comment: ok,to explain - on my product view page the layout is as follows - there is the product title, then add to wish list and below this is the price and below this again is the add to cart button, and just below the add to cart button is the short description, so that is the layout. The sku shows just under the short description currently and what I need is to have the sku code on top just below the product title which is on the very top of the page, so it will be clearly visible there.

Comment: so you can move that code in this file after title simple it will working

Comment: @Leon. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @KeyulShah. Actually I'm supporting a clean website :)

Comment: @Marius Yes That is good for us and other users.

Comment: added code to top in view.phtml works great - thanks again