# how can i show Min Qty "min_qty" As MOQ at Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, quantity, view.phtml

I have read the below post to show **sku** but now i need to show **Minimum Order Qty** on product page. Please guide me how can i show Minimum order quantity.

Post is :

[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42511/sku-in-magento-product-page-description?answertab=oldest#tab-top[1](http://[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42511/sku-in-magento-product-page-description?answertab=oldest#tab-top][1])](http://[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42511/sku-in-magento-product-page-description?answertab=oldest#tab-top][1])

Answer (score 0):

Working code are below.

```
<?php
$loadProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $_product->getId() ); ?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Minimum Quantity:') ?>
    <span class="h1"><?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($loadProduct); ?></span>Piece/s
</label>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that by adding at your view.phtml

```
<?php if ($_product->getMinimumQuantity()):?>
       <div class="minimum-quantity">
            <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getMinimumQuantity()), 'min_qty') ?></div>
                </div>
  <?php endif;?>
```